# JS: Change row background color on specific column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on this [table](http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/434-2/) that as to be managed by the client. I want to know if is possible to change the color of the **entire** row when in the "Status" column he writes the word "vermietet".

In this case when the client write "vermietet" the rows that contains that word change background color in orange.

Any JS tips?

Thanks in adivce.
EDIT:

I tried this

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(document.body)var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('column-10');

for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; ++i) {
 var col = cols[i];

 if (col.innerHTML === 'vermietet') {
   var parent = col;

   while((parent = parent.parentElement).tagName !== 'TR');

   var found = parent.childNodes;

   for (var j = 0; j < found.length; ++j) {
     var td = found[j];

     if (td.tagName === 'TD') {
       td.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
     }
   }
 }
 } 
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS solution:

```
    var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('column-10');

    for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; ++i) {
     var col = cols[i];

     if (col.innerHTML === 'vermietet') {
       var parent = col;

       while((parent = parent.parentElement).tagName !== 'TR');

       var found = parent.childNodes;

       for (var j = 0; j < found.length; ++j) {
         var td = found[j];

         if (td.tagName === 'TD') {
           td.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Do i haveto include the `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` 'cause is Wordpress?

Comment: it depends. If you are just rendering table than answer is yes. If user can edit information than you need to call this piece of code anytime user finished editing.

Comment: Delete this string "$(document.body)"